# Unexpected error while obtaining UI hierarchy java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: appium, uiautomatorviewer

While using UIAutomatorViewer to take the screenshot of my device, I am getting the below error. Please note that my appium is stopped.
[image: UIAutomatorViewer Error]

Comment: If you have the desktop version of Appium Server running, stop the server and re-start it.  For what it's worth, I'm fairly certain you don't really need to have it running in order to inspect the app, but running it can cause this problem.

Comment: Hi Bill, as I have mentioned, it is stopped.

Comment: I missed that part, sorry.  Are you running an emulator or a direct-connect device?  Does `adb devices` recognize it?

Comment: Yeah a direct connected android device. Yeah using adb devices I can see my device as listed.

Comment: Then I have to ask the next obvious set of questions: did you exit and restart the UIAutomator?  Did you try loading the Appium server? (I may be wrong on whether or not it's -always- not required)  Did you try just plain rebooting?  If adb recognizes the device, so should UIAutomator.  How are you launching the UIAutomator?

Comment: Are you starting the UIAutomator using the batch file in the SDK?  `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\uiautomatorviewer.bat` for me.

Comment: Have you had any progress?

Comment: Hi Bill - Yes the uiautomator have been restarted several times,even I did reboot my system twice. I am launching the UIAutomatorViewer using the batch file from within the bin folder inside tools. No progress so far. Thinking of redownloading the SDK packages.

Comment: Any solution is found for "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" ?I am also getting the same error in Linux with SDK 29 and phone is Android 10 .

Comment: Same issue for me also. Did anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solution you need to update your SDK . it's cause sometime becuase your android device is have high version than your SDK . or
**Please just update your Android Studio to the last version.**